# why handleMessage run in ui thread While I created handler with background thread looper?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

why `handleMessage` run in ui thread while I created handler with background thread looper? this looper does not belong to the ui thread but `alertdialog` is shown correctly and without crashing, while an error should be given.

Excuse me if the question is not clear, because I do not know English well

```java
public class ToastService extends Service {

    private HandlerThread thread;
    private Looper looper;
    ServiceHandler handler;
    public static int num=0;
    int idd=0;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("say","created");
        thread=new HandlerThread("mhm", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();
        looper=thread.getLooper();
        handler=new ServiceHandler(looper);
    }

    @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {




        int messageIntent=0;
        if (intent!=null){
            messageIntent=intent.getIntExtra("myMessage",0);
            Log.i("sayonStartCommand",messageIntent+"");
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "ook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Message message=new Message();
        idd=messageIntent;
        message.what=0;
        message.arg1=startId;

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("say",messageIntent);
        message.setData(bundle);

        handler.sendMessage(message);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("say","finish xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.mcontext)
                .setTitle("ok")
                .setMessage("message").show();
            int i=msg.getData().getInt("say");
            Log.i("say",i+"");
            if (idd==3){
                stopSelf(msg.arg1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I found no solution and no one knew the cause.

Answer (score 0):

`looper=thread.getLooper();` this looper still runs on the main thread. So the `Handler` created with that looper also handles message in the main thread.

If you want to create a `Handler` that handles messages in the background thread.

```
 class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

Comment: looper=thread.getLooper(); this looper still runs on the main thread!!!! But the looper belongs to background thread Actually looper belongs to HandlerThread Which has already been started So how is it run on the ui thread?

Comment: If you try to debug it. You'll see `looper` has `main` in its value.